# convert 12 hour format to 24 hour format time in golang

Tags: go

In golang I have not found any way to convert 12 hour format string time to 24 hour format as below:

```
07:05:45PM to 19:05:45
```

I have tried below using layout

```
layout := "Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006"
/*
 * Write your code here.
 */
//layout := "3:04PM"
t,_ := time.Parse(layout,s)
fmt.Println(t)
```

Output is:

```
07:05:45PM
```

I have looked for answers similar to this but it is not helping everyone is using whole layout. I found answers in another language but not in go.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    layout1 := "03:04:05PM"
    layout2 := "15:04:05"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout1, "07:05:45PM")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(t.Format(layout1))
    fmt.Println(t.Format(layout2))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Ypn2-lEF_Zs

Output:

```
07:05:45PM
19:05:45
```

---

Reference: [package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants)

Answer (score 9):

The key is to understand how to write the `layout` argument. According to [godoc](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse), the reference time for `layout` is:

```
Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
```

Each string element of a date has a specific numerical value relevant to it:

| String | Represents |
| --- | --- |
| 1 or 01 or Jan | month |
| 2 or 02 | day of month |
| 3 or 03 or 15 | hour |
| 4 or 04 | minute |
| 5 or 05 | second |
| 6 or 06 or 2006 | year |
| -0700 or MST | timezone representation |
| PM | period of day |

You need to rewrite this date to your format as the layout for parse. You only need to include the elements to your need. So only the hour, minute, second and AM/PM is important. Reference time `15:04:05` should be written as `03:04:05PM`.

Just use the rewritten time as the layout parameter:

```golang
import time

...


t, _ := time.Parse("03:04:05PM", "07:05:45PM")
fmt.Println(t.Format("15:04:05"))
```

Output:

```
19:05:45
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const (
    layoutDateTime   = "02 Jan 2006 15:04:05"
)

dateTimePM, _ := time.Parse(layoutDateTime + " PM", "07 Nov 2019 11:31:30 PM")
dateTimeAM, _ := time.Parse(layoutDateTime + " PM", "07 Nov 2019 11:31:30 AM")
```

This has successfully converted both AM,PM dates correctly.